# Which solution to execute the right stored procedure according to parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I found 2 Q/A that are the same (according to me) but for which the given answers are different and so I wanted your opinion upon the right answer (or maybe this is actually not the same question...)

Here are the questions:

> Your application contains a stored procedure for each country. Each
>   stored procedure accepts an employee identification number through the
>   @EmpID parameter. You need to build a single process for each employee
>   that will execute the appropriate stored procedure based on the
>   country of residence.  Which approach should you use?
>
> 1. A SELECT statement that includes CASE
> 2. Cursor
> 3. BULK INSERT
> 4. View
> 5. A user-defined function
>
> Correct Answer: 5 (A user-defined function)

The second:

> Your application contains a stored procedure for each country. Each
>   stored procedure accepts an employee identification number through the
>   @EmpID parameter. You plan to build a single process for each employee
>   that will execute the stored procedure based on the
>   country of residence.  Which approach should you use?
>
> 1. A recursive stored procedure
> 2. Trigger
> 3. An UPDATE statement that includes CASE
> 4. Cursor
> 5. The foreach SQLCLR statement
>
> Correct Answer: 4 (Cursor)

In my opinion, the Cursor solution was right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is a bit strange.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320(v=sql.110).aspx) for creating a function explicitly says:

> - User-defined functions cannot call a stored procedure, but can call an extended stored procedure.

It is unclear what author's intention is, but my reading of the question rules of answer (5).

I might not prefer a cursor for the work, but of the options specified, it would seem to be the only applicable solution.

Answer (score 2):

On the first question, you cannot call a stored procedure from a select, insert, a view, or a function, so that only leaves a cursor.  But that is a poor answer.  A cursor is not "a single process".  It is a pointer, a tool you can use within a single process.  So if you use a cursor, to loop through a series of employee records, you are probably within a stored procedure.

To me that would be the answer, "a stored procedure", which is included in your second question, kind of.  In the second question it says "recursive stored procedure".  The recursive part bothers me because the stored procedure does **not** need to be recursive to call another stored procedure.  So option 1 on question 2 is halfway decent, but has problems.

I rule out options 3,4 and 5 on the second question for the same reasons as I ruled out all options in question 1.  That leaves the Trigger.  It is entirely possible that you could call this country stored procedure on a trigger that runs anytime a new employee is inserted or updated.  That might be a good solution depending on the application.  So that leaves question 2 with one and a half good answers (#2 and #1).

Bottom line, question 1 has no really good answers, and question 2 has two that are at least semi-acceptable.  If it were me asking the question, I would use the options from question 1, but replace option number 2 (the cursor) with "A stored procedure".

Comment: Thank you also for your useful feedback